# Using urllib to Download

Tags: python, selenium, download, urllib2, urllib

Im creating a program to download music. right now some of it is in selenium but im trying to slowly s=change it completely to urllib but im stuck at the download part.  when i run it it works fine but i dont get the downloaded song

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2, urllib, urllister
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

raw_i=raw_input("Search: ")
x = urllib.quote_plus(raw_i)

site1 = urllib2.urlopen(' Youtube Search Link ')
y = site1.read()
parser = urllister.URLLister()
parser.feed(y)

parser.close()


for url in parser.urls:
    if "watch?v=" in url: 
        v = url

        break


vid = ("youtube link %s"%v)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("Youtube to Mp3 link")


elem = driver.find_element_by_id("youtube-url")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys(vid)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
download = driver.page_source

parser = urllister.URLLister()
parser.feed(download)
parser.close
driver.quit()

for url in parser.urls:
    if "/get?video_id" in url: 
        down = url

download_url = ("Download link")
urllib.urlretrieve(download_url)
```

like i said i don't get an error message but i cant find my downloaded song

Comment: `urlretreive()` accepts a filename as the second argument. Youtube has API that should allow to get urls without web-scraping.

Comment: yeah i ended up doing that ans ill look into that Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve):

> **urllib.urlretrieve**
>   Return a tuple (filename, headers) where filename is the local file
>   name under which the object can be found

So try this at the end of your code:

```
download_url = ("Download link")
filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(download_url)
print filename
```